# How can I select the key as the column from JSON column in CQL table?

Tags: json, cassandra, cql

I have created the following table in CQL:

`CREATE TABLE new_table (
idRestaurant INT, 
restaurant map<text,varchar>,
InspectionDate date, 
ViolationCode VARCHAR,
ViolationDescription VARCHAR, 
CriticalFlag VARCHAR, Score INT, GRADE VARCHAR, 
PRIMARY KEY (InspectionDate )) ;`

Then, I have inserted the data by `jar`, and I got the `restaurant column` value is like `json/dictionary`

`select restarutant from new_table;` is like the following result:
[image]

In normal SQL for selecting the json column's key value should be `select json_col.key from table` But that does not work for CQL, how can I select the JSON's key value as the column or for the WHERE condition filtering?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using map, I would better to change the table's schema to following:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
  idRestaurant INT, 
  restaurant_key text,
  restaurant_value text,
  InspectionDate date, 
  ViolationCode VARCHAR,
  ViolationDescription VARCHAR, 
  CriticalFlag VARCHAR, 
  Score INT, 
  GRADE VARCHAR, 
  PRIMARY KEY (InspectionDate, restaurant_key )) ;
```

then you can select either individual row based on the `restaurant_key` with query like:

```
select * from new_table where idRestaurant = ? and restaurant_key = ?
```

or select everything for restaurant with:

```
select * from new_table where idRestaurant = ?
```